# RedShift tuning to time separated table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Currently I handle big data in redshift.
I would like to ask you a best table schema.

Data set on the table is like this.

```
tmp_tbl_yyyy_MM
user_id int,
position_x int,
position_y int,
date date,
type int
sortkey (date)
```

and 1 bilion data is inserted per month.
I usually scan data of the past 3 months, and
according to [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-time-series-tables.html),
time separated table seems to be good. 
Therefore I separated the table by month like "_yyyy_MM"

Here is an example query I often run.

```
select user_id from(
select * from tmp_tbl_yyyy_MM
unionall
select * from tmp_tbl_yyyy_MM
) 
where
(position_x between ? and ?
and position_y between ? and ?)
or
(position_x between ? and ?
and position_y between ? and ?)
or ...
and date between ? and ?
and type = ?;
```

position_x,position_y conditions are repeated over 1000 times.

This query's plan is sequential scan, so its very slow.
Teach me the best way to get same results.

I guess the points are table, query and sortkey.

- Unionall is bad?
  Shouldn't I separate the table by month?
- Where clause should be in the subqueries?
- Should I set interleaved sortkey to all contdition like position_x,position_y,date,type

Comment: The thing slowing down your query is all that OR conditions.. If you can find a way to reduce them your query will run a lot faster. UNION ALL is not bad

Comment: thanks sagi:) Im gonna try to reduce OR condition though I have no idea now.

Comment: If you give us your entire query and the logic, we can help you

Comment: You can also add "type" to your compound sort key, and include the date range in your "view" definition.

Comment: Thank you. interleaved sortkey is not good? redshift creates some blocks for each sortkey, and when I use union condition Im curious about how it works.